# Place a checkbox on a collapsible header and store ID information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am making an app using HTML5 and jquery mobile. I have 1 of the pages where I take in input from a server via ajax and display it on a collapsible drop down menu in the following format:

```
Collapsible tab title1
Id: 1
Account: 1
Amount: 500

Collapsible tab title2
Id: 2
Account: 2
Amount: 500

and so on.
```

I want to have a checkbox on this tab title which when ticked, will store the value of the id in a variable.

For example:

```
Collapsible tab title1 checkbox ticked. (for this title1, id is 1)
var identity = 1; (store 1 in a variable)
```

Right at the bottom of the page I have a CONFIRM button. When that it is clicked, this information is sent out to a url www.awebsite.com/id=1

I have finished up with every bit of the app less this part. I need help in 2 areas.

1.How do I add a checkbox to my collapsible tab title.

2.Upon checking a checkbox, how do I store the ID information in a variable.

I have solved the part where I send out the variable information to the url. Can someone please help me with the 2 parts. I tried looking up tutorials but information is separated where either they talk about how to make a collapsible set or how to create a checkbox. Also didn't find any examples on storing the information via checkbox.

The following are the codes for the page and code that gets information from the server. Thanks.

html

```
<div data-role="page" id="unpaidBills" data-theme="e">
            <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Unpaid Bills</h1>    
        </header>
        <article data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="unpaidList">
                <!--wil fill up with info from database-->
            </div>
        </article>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1></h1>
        </footer>
        </div>
```

script

```
$.getJSON("http://mywebsite.com/public/user/listunpaidbills/",function(data){
            //Loop for each element on the data
            $.each(data,function(elem){
                var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
                //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to bills List
                $("<h1/>",{
                    text:data[elem].reference //this is the title
                }).appendTo(wrap);   
                $("<p/>",{
                    text:"ID: "+ data[elem].id
                }).appendTo(wrap);   
                $("<p/>",{
                    text:"Account: "+ data[elem].account
                }).appendTo(wrap);        
                $("<p/>",{
                    text:"Amount: "+ data[elem].amount
                }).appendTo(wrap);
                wrap.appendTo('#unpaidList');    
            })//end of for each loop
            $( "#unpaidList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
        })
```

Edit:

```
<div data-role="page" id="apple" data-theme="e">
          <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          </div>

          <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">           
              <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
                <legend>Header</legend>

                <div data-role="controlgroup">
                  <label for="id">ID: 1</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" value="id">
                </div>  
              <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Confirm">
              </fieldset>           
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? Too simple for you?

Comment: A downvote sometimes means, "try! when you're stuck, let's know". Look at the positive side ;)

Comment: Thanks for those words. I am stuck with both getting a checkbox on my collapsible header and storing the variable. I didn't add all codes cos nothing was working and I have been at it for a couple of day now. I just edited and added what I am trying currently which is to at least get the header to have a checkbox first which is not working.